# How to find a LI with particular content in an UL with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

In the following `UL` with id of `CP_main_approvalist` I want to find the `LI` that has "**Awating authorisation**" string and to extract that text from it:

[image]

There can be many `LI`s in that `UL`. In this case there are only two.

Comment: Do you know beforehand what the content or part of the content of the li is that you are looking for?

Comment: dynamically created by server side @CarlBinalla

Comment: @Sitethief awating authorisation string will be there in li

Comment: @Roy That would target the **authorized** list, which is not what OP is asking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access it by: `$("#CP_Main_approvalList li:contains('Awating authorisation')")`,

So something like this:

```js
$("#CP_Main_approvalList li:contains('Awating authorisation')").css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="CP_Main_approvalList">
  <li>1. Authorised by...</li>
  <li>2. Awating authorisation from....</li>
</ul>
```

To extract the text from the specified `LI` you will have to call a `text()` method on the resulting set:

```
$("#CP_Main_approvalList li:contains('Awating authorisation')").text()
```

But you have to be careful, since if there is more than one `LI` with such text, it will extract it from all the matching elements. In order to extract only from the first one use:

```
$("#CP_Main_approvalList li:contains('Awating authorisation')").first().text()
```

Or [:eq(idx)](https://api.jquery.com/eq/#eq-index) (`idx` is 0-based) selector, instead of `first()` to pick the element with some other index.

**UPDATE**

So far it was the direct answer to your question, but in general this technique is far from the best practice, provides bad performance (query selector has to look inside every `LI` and match the actual text) and is prone to potential future errors (what if someone decides to change that text - the whole extraction logic will break). Consider adding appropriate class name or data attribute to the corresponding elements (`authorized` and `authorizing` for example) and differentiate between them by it.

Comment: Supposed that you want to get the text you can use `.text()`

Comment: how to extract the text jelena lucic which is present  after from ?

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: @nikhiljain from what I see you are particularly reluctant to accept answers to your questions (single accepted answer since April last year). People look at your ask/check rate when they answer your questions. If it will drop any further, you might stop receiving any responses.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this by using children or has function like below:

```
$("#CP_Main_approvalList").children("li contains('Awating authorisation')").prop('innerHTML');
```

OR

```
$("#CP_Main_approvalList").has("li contains('Awating authorisation')").prop('innerHTML');
```

Answer (score -4):

You can select the `ul` by using the id selector:

```
$("#CP_Main_approvalList")
```

Then, add the `li` and make sure it contains the text you need

```
li:contains('Awaiting authorisation')
```

And to make sure it works I changed the text color...

```js
$("#CP_Main_approvalList li:contains('Awaiting authorisation')").css("color", "green");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="CP_Main_approvalList">
  <li>1. Authorised by ..... </li>
  <li>2. Awaiting authorisation from ..... </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: LOL, it took me a few minutes to post my asnwer and meanwhile someone else posted similar answer, now it seems like I copied it :) Thanks for the downvotes :)

Comment: Lol, and your comment and your edits are not going to save you ;)

Comment: I don't care, it still a correct answer though, if you'll check my answers history you can see I don't copy answers. Keeping it live just for fun

Comment: May be you are right, but the coincidence is still quite funny :)

Comment: Well, it's a simple question with a simple solution that hardly can be written differently...

Comment: How come you wrote it with the same misspelling? The right word would be `Authorization`, no?

Comment: Copied it from the OP... I worked with 2 screens to copy the code since it was on image...

Comment: @jayarjo Both are correct. "Authorisation" is mainly British and "authorization" mainly American spelling.

Comment: Actually, when looking again, I used 5 dots on the `li` text. Seems legit now ?

Comment: @jayarjo you also misspelled "Awating"... Seems like someone else copied from you... (Shah)

Comment: I just wanted to check your thinking behind the "typo". That's exactly what I did. So maybe the humankind is the collective hive mind after all :D